# Me sale error en puerto 3306 en MySQL Workbench ¿Alguna solución?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, localhost

[image: error por puerto 3306]
[image: error por puerto 3306]

Hola comunidad!

Tengo el error de localhost, he intentado cambiar el host con XAMPP con la configuración de MySQL, y nada, aunque cambie de host-puertos , no puedo utilizar Workbench.

En la documentación puedo cambiar de número de host, y lo he cambiado, pero igual persiste el error, he intentado desinstalar he instalar, he cambiado la configuración de windows y nada.

Adjunto imágenes

gracias!

Comment: En la segunda captura te explica que mirar ¿lo has hecho?
Está el MySQL encendido? En la misma màquina? usa el puerto 3306?
No estará corriendo en una máquina virtual ( docker, virtualbox...) usando una dirección diferente?

Comment: Verifica lo que te comenta @ArnauCastellví. Y, en vez de conectar por Workbench, intenta conectar por consola, ahí podrás ver con mayor claridad si tienes mysql debidamente instalado, en qué puerto está corriendo, qué permisos tienen los usuarios, etc.

Comment: Si MySQL esta encendido, chequearía si el usuario creado tiene todos los permisos requeridos y la otra opción es si la clave utilizada por el usuario es la correcta.